# "Waited for * || true but it wasn't there " each time I run apt

Tags: apt

Every time I try to install ANYTHING with `apt-get`,i get this error

```
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there     
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

I have looked at many forums but none of them seem to have any answer.

Any help would be much appreciated at this time!

(everything must be done via command line, 13.04 server)

Tried Braiam's command, this was the output + command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-pr
econfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"                 
[sudo] password for swech:                                                      
--apt: 1: --apt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string                       
-bash: true;};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How are you connecting? I had a [similar problem when I wasn't connecting via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485682/apt-get-dpkg-fails-from-a-bluetooth-serial-port-but-succeed-from-the-physi#comment986647_485682).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you somehow screwed up your configuration scripts, the reason why is happening is because `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};` doesn't exist in your scripts so you may have to create it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

Then try again.

Comment: Output in question, new edit.

Comment: @HairTriggerHosting you sure you copy/pasted correctly?

Comment: pasted fine, although I got the error, apt seems to be working just fine. I am getting an error after installation tho, again with dpkg.http://askubuntu.com/questions/386762/trying-to-install-no-ip-but-getting-error

Answer (score -1):

try-

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install
```

then see if error prompts.

Comment: command fails, I don't think the problem lies with apt.