# Trying to install no-ip, but getting error

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to install noip dynamic update client on ubuntu server 13.04. I am able to get through the auto config up to the point where it tries to create the debian package. Here is the error log.

```
dpkg-deb: building package `noip-2.1.9' in `/usr/local/src/noip-2.1.9-1/noip-2.1
.9_1-1_amd64.deb'.                                                              
dpkg-deb: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:                                  
 wait for subprocess gzip -9c failed: No child processes
```

(everything must be done via command line)

In response to a comment, I am calling the process by a few commands.

```
 apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
dir
cd  noip-2.1.9-1/
checkinstall
```

I am using [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-no-ip2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts-in-order-to-host-servers-on-a-dynamic-ip-address) as a guide

Comment: How are you calling it? I mean, please add the command you are typing.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see, unless I'm blatantly missing something, is that you're running with the wrong permissions. Instead, try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential  
sudo checkinstall        
cd /usr/local/src/             
sudo wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz   
tar xf noip-duc-linux.tar.gz  
dir  
cd  noip-2.1.9-1/  
sudo checkinstall
```

Running with root permissions should at least narrow down the issue, get you on the right track. I checked the info listing for checkinstall, it recommends that in most cases, you use it with root privileges.

Comment: `checkinstall` command not found