# I cant seem to install any packages on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt

I originally installed the LAMP package on installation of the server. Took me ages to get the web server to work and then I found that PHP hadnt been installed as part of the package, which is odd as it should have been. I also tried to install SSH server so I could log in using Putty. Any time I try to install anything I get the following:-

```
jim@Unseen:~$ sudo apt-get -f install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysq
l                                                                               
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
libapache2-mod-php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).           
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).                    
The following additional packages will be installed:                            
  libmcrypt4 php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt                                               
Suggested packages:                                                             
  libmcrypt-dev mcrypt                                                          
The following NEW packages will be installed                                    
  libmcrypt4 php php-mcrypt php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt                                
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.             
Need to get 0 B/83.5 kB of archives.                                            
After this operation, 326 kB of additional disk space will be used.             
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y                                                
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there     
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

I've tried apt-get clean. I've tried the standard apt-get. I've run apt-get update. Nothing I try seems to work. Can anyone suggest anything to help me please. I am new to ubuntu and getting very frustrated with it. Thanks in advance

Edit:

I tried the fix suggested on a similar post that refers to 14.0* although my server is 16.04.4:-

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

This did not work and reported that 70debconf did not exist.

---

Edit 2

I corrected the command string as suggested to:-

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {\"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconf
igure --apt || true\";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

It returned a prompt with no messages so I presume it worked

I then ran the following:-

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And returned exactly the same as before:-

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
The following additional packages will be installed:                            
  ncurses-term openssh-sftp-server python3-requests python3-urllib3             
  ssh-import-id                                                                 
Suggested packages:                                                             
  ssh-askpass rssh molly-guard monkeysphere python3-ndg-httpsclient             
  python3-openssl python3-pyasn1                                                
The following NEW packages will be installed                                    
  ncurses-term openssh-server openssh-sftp-server python3-requests              
  python3-urllib3 ssh-import-id                                                 
0 to upgrade, 6 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.             
Need to get 0 B/746 kB of archives.                                             
After this operation, 5,652 kB of additional disk space will be used.           
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y                                                
Preconfiguring packages ...                                                     
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there     
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

Edit 3

A thought occurred to me after some terrific help. Before these problem started I installed Webmin as a quick way to remotely access the server from my desktop. I tried to to install Openssh-server through webmin and to my surprise it worked. So the conclusion looks like webmin has somehow interfered with the native functions on the server. I'm sure this shouldn't happen and wonder if I should report it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Waited for \* || true but it wasn't there " each time I run apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386314/waited-for-true-but-it-wasnt-there-each-time-i-run-apt)

Comment: Hang on, that question was not properly answered, I think, although it has an accepted answer.

Comment: I read that and it didnt help me at all.

Comment: I'll retract my vote. Meanwhile, please add the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` to your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused.. why would I need to add /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf to my question if that refers to something in 14.0* and not 16.04.4.  I've added it but cant understand why

Comment: Of course your situation may be different but on my 16.04 system I can confirm that there is a file called 70debconf which contains the requested line. However, if you're convinced that is no solution, we will investigate this no further.

Comment: As I said in my original description of the issue I'm new to Ubuntu so have no idea what is there or not nor what is relevant to each version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with initial answer, the inner set of double quotes need to be escaped

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {\"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true\";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

I can confirm that /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf exists on both my Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.10 boxes. The contents of this file on my Ubuntu 16.04 box are

```
// Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed.
// If you don't like it, comment it out.
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
```

Comment: I tried the string as you corrected and the system accepted it. However I still have the same problem.

Comment: Ok, 2 things to try; 1. see if /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure is executable, try `/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --help`. 2. Open /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf and comment out the `Dpkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs` line by prepending it with `//`

Comment: I've just had a look at the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf and this is what it contains:- "code" // Pre-configure all packages with debconf before they are installed.
// If you don't like it, comment it out.
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
Dpg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";}; 'code'

Comment: Hmm, so you've the same line repeated 3 times but there appears to be a typo in the second, this is possibly the issue. Remove the 2nd and 3rd `Dpkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs` lines and try my suggestions in the 2nd comment

Comment: I tried commenting out the line like you said and this is the error I got:- `dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:                                      
 waiting for subprocess dpkg-split failed: No child processes                   
W: Waited for dpkg --assert-multi-arch but it wasn't there - dpkgGo (10: No chil
d processes)                                                                    
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg couldn't be waited for.                            
E: Couldn't wait for subprocess - waitpid (10: No child processes)`

Comment: Did running `/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --help` return anything?

Comment: If I the 1st test you suggested I get :-                                                         `Can't ignore signal CHLD, forcing to default.                                   
Usage: dpkg-preconfigure [options] [debs]                                       
       --apt                    Apt mode.                                       
  -f, --frontend                Specify debconf frontend to use.                
  -p, --priority                Specify minimum priority question to show.      
        --terse                 Enable terse mode.`

Comment: I was wondering if the installation of webmin has had an effect on this issue. I tried to install openssh-server with webmin and it has worked which seems a bit odd. Do you think webmin has overridden the normal function of apt-get?